# gimp 2.10.20 issue with scaling blurred images

Tags: gimp

for some reason in the gimp 2.10.20 version of gimp, scaling blurred image with transparent background(or layer) has problems. I just blurred a circle on a transparent layer, and I tried to scale it, but the gaussian blur jumps back to  a smaller strength as if it's trying to preserve the blur, as a result I end up with a much thicker circle than I'd expected to. I think this might be a bug, but I'm cautious to report it , so I'm asking to confirm it here, or is it a tool feature somewhere with a swatch to toggle on/off?

Full demo here: [in this video](https://vimeo.com/user123979096/review/462189729/35dea67b22)

Comment: The video link is broken. Also I can't replicate this problem, but I'm using 2.10.18.  Maybe it's a bug, or a new feature?

Comment: @BillyKerr, the link is working, just the title of the video is error.

Comment: Nope. It says "Sorry, we couldn’t find that page".

Comment: @BillyKerr , really? I'm able to play the video.... that's strange. I've uploaded the video here if you'd like to check it out: https://ufile.io/5zzancwh

Comment: The download link worked, I had a quick look, but [I can't replicate this in GIMP 2.10.18](https://imgur.com/ThFa9zk) - so I guess it could be some kind of bug in 2.10.20